# How to prevent paperclip gem from deleting old files when new files are uploaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

An app uses paperclip to handle file uploads for user avatars.

Paperclip currently deletes old files when new ones are files, however, I wish for the users to see a history of what they have uploaded.

Is there a way to prevent paperclip from deleting old files when new files are uploaded?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`has_attached_file` has a `:keep_old_files` options you can set. For example:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :keep_old_files => true
```

Source: http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file